# Ionic 3 camera function with latitude,longitude and timestamp plugin

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic and application development. I am working on a project right now involving image, location and time. what I need to do is take a picture and add the location and timestamp into the image.i've been searching everywhere but I can't seem to find any plugins that could help me with this. I'd be grateful to anyone who could point me in the right direction. So far I have considered combining IMG tag and DIV tag that contain latitude, longitude, and timestamp into a container DIV tag and manage to do so but don't have a way to save that container DIV as an image in android. Please lend to me some wisdom.

Comment: Do you want to add the timestamp and other info printed on the image or Just want to display it along with the image

Comment: I want it to be printed on the image so that I can save it in the device photo gallery. I tried using html2canvas but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Chec out this plugin https://github.com/toboqus/Cordova-Plugin-Image-Handler

Comment: I cant install the plugin it kept saying

Error: Failed to fetch plugin https://github.com/toboqus/Cordova-Plugin-Image-Handler.git via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/toboqus/Cordova-Plugin-Image-Handler.git
npm ERR! fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'
 error code: 128